# R: Column names lost using index

Tags: r

When writing: `df.stats <- aggregate(var1 ~ var2, data=df, FUN=mean)`
df.stats keeps the column names (var1 andvar2).
When writing: `df.stats <- aggregate(df[,1] ~ df[,2], data=df, FUN=mean)`
df.stats columns are called df[,1] and df[,2] - and the original column names are lost.

How can I use indexes and still keep the original column names?
*Why do I want to use indexes? Because, I don't want to change my code every time I analyse a new column/factor in my dataset.*

Comment: welcome to SO. perhaps if you showed more of your code and provided a minimal working example as you were prompted to do when you submitted a question it would make it easier for folks to assist you.

Comment: You would use list indexing and the data frame method.  `aggregate(iris[1], iris[5], mean)` versus `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, mean)`

Comment: @RichScriven Nice one.

Comment: aren't you changing your code when you change the indexes you're looking at?

Comment: @RichScriven Yes, that's what I wanted! Thanks (Y)
P.S.: Since it looks so simple, and I didn't find it/out myself, I should really have to dive much deeper to understand the basics of R.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have a bunch of factors of a similar kind which I have to go through, and changing the var names everywhere would take too long.

Answer (score 3):

If you're truly wanting to use indexes and a forumla interface:

```
index_agg <- function(formula, data, FUN, ...) {

   require(formula.tools)

   left <- as.numeric(lhs(formula))
   right <- as.numeric(rhs(formula))
   f <- paste0(colnames(data[,c(left, right)]), collapse=" ~ ")

   aggregate(as.formula(f), data=data, FUN=FUN, ...)

}

head(index_agg(6 ~ 1, data=mtcars, FUN=mean))
##    mpg     wt
## 1 10.4 5.3370
## 2 13.3 3.8400
## 3 14.3 3.5700
## 4 14.7 5.3450
## 5 15.0 3.5700
## 6 15.2 3.6075

head(index_agg(5 ~ 1, data=mtcars, FUN=mean))
##    mpg  drat
## 1 10.4 2.965
## 2 13.3 3.730
## 3 14.3 3.210
## 4 14.7 3.230
## 5 15.0 3.540
## 6 15.2 3.110
```

If you don't want `formula.tools` as a dependency:

```
index_agg <- function(formula, data, FUN, ...) {

   left <- as.numeric(toString(formula[3]))
   right <- as.numeric(toString(formula[2]))
   f <- paste0(colnames(data[,c(left, right)]), collapse=" ~ ")

   aggregate(as.formula(f), data=data, FUN=FUN, ...)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setNames()`. Example shown for `iris` dataset

```
  setNames(aggregate(iris[,1] ~ iris[,2], data = iris, mean), colnames(iris)[1:2])
```